# is it possible to to store the contact in phonebook in gujarati (any local language) ? in android

Tags: android, contacts

is it possible to to store the contact in phonebook in gujarati (any local language) and also display it in same language in android? if possible then how to implement in our own android application?

Comment: how it is possible? and how can we implement in our own android application.. coz it requires changes at system level?

Comment: not sure but localization concept will help you

Comment: i am trying that already but that we can use in our app. but i want to change the language on android system level.. without that we can not display the contact list in our phonebook in local language.. so i want to do that..

Comment: ok let me give a try wil get back to u